# how to use GPPNative share dialog by login with GIDSignin google

Tags: ios, google-plus, share

I am using GIDSignin SDK for Google + login, which will login inside the app. But i COuld not share with GPP Native share dialog, once i logged in using GIDSignin SDK.

Getting an error : GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the native sharebox.

Comment: Did you got any solution on this?

Comment: Did you got any solution on this?

Comment: Not yet.. anyone tried on this?